# How to send values React Hook(props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made My code.

When Click the button A, appear AAA.
Or Click the button B, appear BBB, Click the button C, appear CCC.

```
// Main > RightMain.js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function RightMain() {

    const [screen, setScreen] = useState('');
    const A = () => {
        setScreen('A')
    }
    const B = () => {
        setScreen('B')
    }
    const C = () => {
        setScreen('C')
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={A}>A</button>
            <button onClick={B}>B</button>
            <button onClick={C}>C</button>
            {screen === 'A' && <div>AAA</div>}
            {screen === 'B' && <div>BBB</div>}
            {screen === 'C' && <div>CCC</div>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default RightMain
```

And I wanna separate My Code(RightMain.js).

When I Click the Button on the RightMain.js.

The Result appear's on the Formations.js like the image below.

[image]

But I don kno how to bring value(RightMain.js's screen) to the Formations.js.

[image]

```
// Main > LeftMain.js
import React from 'react'
import RadioBtn from './LeftMain/RadioBtn';
import Formation from './LeftMain/Formation';

function LeftMain() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <RadioBtn />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Formation />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default LeftMain
```

```
//Main > LeftMain > Formation.js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import RightMain from '../RightMain';

function Formation() {
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Formation
```

Thx

Comment: So you want those 3 buttons under `formation.js` ?

Comment: to pass the values to the `formation.js` file you need to use Context API, and for buttons you must use the event target   `onClick={(e)=> A}` then pass the event to the function

Comment: React is designed to prevent you from doing exactly that, because you'll make your code unmaintainable.
Raise the "screen" state to the closest parent of both right & left.
Replace the A,B,C methods with a reducer (useReducer instead of useState).
Send the reducer to RightMain through props and then to buttons.
Send screen state to LeftMain through props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, LeftMain and RightMain are sibilings, and Formation is a child of LeftMain.

One possible approach is to use Context API.

Something like this should work:

```js
// Define the default value
// or return null and take that into consideration when using "useContext"
export const MyCurrentScreenContext = React.createContext({ 
  setScreen: () => void 0, 
  screen: ''
});

export const MyCurrentScreenProvider = props => {
  const [screen, setScreen] = useState('');

  const value = useMemo(() => ({ screen, setScreen }), [screen, setScreen]);
   
  return (
    <MyCurrentScreenContext.Provider value={value}>
      {props.children}
    </MyCurrentScreenContext.Provider>
  );
}

const Main = () => {
  ...
  return ( 
    <MyCurrentScreenProvider>
      <LeftMain />
      <RightMain />
      ...
    </MyCurrentScreenProvider>
  );
}

const RightMain() {
   const { setScreen } = useContext(MyCurrentScreenContext);
   ....
};

const Formation() {
  const { screen } = useContext(MyCurrentScreenContext);
  ....
};
```

Read more about context api at the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to pass the values down to the child components. If that is correct then you could pass them as parameters when calling it and using props to receive them inside the child component. Something like this.

```
<div>
     <RadioBtn randomVal="value" />
</div>
```